# Android Toast.Set Gravity Causing App To Crash

Tags: android, debugging, toast

I don't understand why my toast is crashing the app.

I have two sets of code, the one I originally did which is crashing and one that I found that is working.

The one the is working creates the toast object and declares the text at the same time.

```
Toast toast = 
Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

The one I made creates the object in the context, sets the text then the gravity and tries to show it.

```
Toast toast = new Toast(QuizActivity.this);
toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,
               R.string.correct_toast,
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Why is this crashing my app?

Comment: Can you add a stack trace to your answer?

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: That `makeText()` call in the second block isn't doing what you think it is. `makeText()` is a static method that returns a `Toast` to be used. It's not initializing `toast` there.

Comment: I'm honestly not experienced enough with Android to do either. Where do I add a trace or see the logcat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173

Comment: @MikeM. I thought it was setting the text in the toast object.

Comment: Nope, it's creating a new `Toast` instance and returning it, but you're not doing anything with the return there. Look at your first block to see how you use the return. It's one of the pitfalls in Java, being able to call static methods on instances.

Comment: Error is 'java.lang.RuntimeException: setView must have been called'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
Toast toast = new Toast(QuizActivity.this);
```

constructs an empty Toast object. You must call setView(View) before you can call show().

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

as it stated in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Comment: Ah ok. So I have to go into the XML create a special container. Make an object out of that and "paint" to it with the toast if I don't just initialize it by setting the text from the get go? that seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: Roughly speaking - yes. And mark my answer as a correct :).

Answer (score 1):

**you can try this**

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,"your string", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a toast object like this.

```
Toast toast = new Toast(QuizActivity.this);
```

This line of code construct an empty Toast object.

Then you have to call the `setView()` , `setDuration()` on your own. `makeText()` method is a static method. So, you can't call it from a toast object.

You can initialize a `Toast` object by calling the method `makeText()` method.

For this reason, the first code is working properly and the second is not.

Comment: What is it doing then when I create the toast object that way?

Answer (score 0):

This is crashing because you are not called setView() method before calling show mehod.

Calling constructor(`Toast toast = new Toast(QuizActivity.this);`) will construct an empty `Toast` object.This object will not contain a *default view* to show,So you have to call setView() method to set a view for the toast.Then only this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting `RuntimeException`.

> 'java.lang.RuntimeException: setView must have been called'

You are just creating an `instance` of `Toast` uisng `"new Toast(QuizActivity.this)"` and you did not set any view for it. You have to set your own custom `layout` to `Toast`.

**SOLUTION:**

```
LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)
        this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// Custom layout
View view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText("Hello world!");

// Toast
Toast toast = new Toast(QuizActivity.this);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

// Set the Toast custom layout
toast.setView(view);
toast.show();
```

**Here is `custom_toast.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_margin="5px"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="50dp" 
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Android Tutorial Custom Toast"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16dp" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help~